# Issues with Basic Authentication Using TCL Rest Package

Tags: rest, tcl, basic-authentication

New to TCL and having an issue with using the `::rest::simple url query ?config? ?body?` command - specifically getting basic authentication to work. The example given here (https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-18/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/rest/rest.html#section4) is as follows:

```
set url   http://twitter.com/statuses/update.json
    set query [list status $text]
    set res [rest::simple $url $query {
        method post
        auth   {basic user password}
        format json
    }]
```

So my attempt is:

```
package require rest
package require json

set url http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/id

set response [rest::simple $url {
    method get
    auth {basic user password}
    format json
}]

puts $response
```

However, I keep getting a 401 error when I try and run the above against a mock API endpoint for GET:

```
"GET /api/id?auth=basic%20user%20password&method=get&format=json HTTP/1.1" 401 -
```

I can make a curl request against that same endpoint using basic auth (with Python as well), and if I disable basic auth on the endpoint this works just fine in TCL:

```
set url http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/id

set response [rest::simple $url {
    method get
    format json
}]

puts $response
```

So it's something to do with the basic auth credentials in the TCL rest module.

Comment: Pay close attention to the number of arguments to `rest::simple` in the example and your version.

Comment: @Shawn Ahh yes thank you. I'm new to the language and was misreading the meaning of ? in the documentation in regards to optional parameters.

Comment: Problem solved then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Shawn's comment pointing out I was misreading the meaning of `?` in TCL docs. Parameters *surrounded* by question marks are optional, rather than parameters followed by question marks. I was interpreting `::rest::simple url query ?config? ?body?` as meaning the query param was optional. If there is no query, you can use an empty query as the required parameter. This ended up working:

```
set response [rest::simple $url {} {
    method get
    auth {basic user password}
    format json
    }]
```